# Kubernetes pod QoS class in Prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, metrics, promql

I would like to add one panel to my Grafana dashboard with the number of Best Effort, Burstable and Guaranteed pods.

I did this approach:

`(kube_pod_status_phase{phase="Running"}==1) and on(pod,namespace) label_replace(container_memory_working_set_bytes{id=~".*burstable.*"} ,"pod","$1","pod_name","(.*)")`

and

`(kube_pod_status_phase{phase="Running"}==1) and on(pod,namespace) label_replace(container_memory_working_set_bytes{id=~".*besteffort.*"} ,"pod","$1","pod_name","(.*)")`

but I do not find the way to obtain the Guaranteed ones. The only approach I've got was:

`(kube_pod_status_phase{phase="Running"}==1) and on(pod,namespace) label_replace(container_memory_working_set_bytes{id!~".*burstable.*|.*besteffort.*"} ,"pod","$1","pod_name","(.*)")`

Is there any other way to obtain this information?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like for Guaranteed pods the system create a unique slide with the pod id in the form of `/kubepods.slice/kubepods-pod<pod-id>...` so the following query should return all the pods running in guaranteed QoS class

```
# Cluster wide
container_memory_working_set_bytes{container!="POD",id=~".*kubepods-pod.*"}

# On a specific node
container_memory_working_set_bytes{container!="POD",id=~".*kubepods-pod.*", node="node1.example.com"}
```